# is there a time limit interval for when you can activate windows on same pc

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-activation

after moving my windows to ssd drive, the license would not activate anymore and so I restored a backup to my hdd, however it still would not activate. But a couple of hours later I tried and it activated. So I assumed that when I moved it to sdd, I didn't give it enough time to activate. Now I moved it back to the ssd drive (I never learn) and gave it about a day and still wont activate.

I want to know whether there is a limit to how many time to can activate a copy in a day. Keep in mind this is on the same computer and im not concurrently running the same copy.

Comment: i suggest you to read this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/useterms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an activation limit. I have never seen any documentation from Microsoft indicating this is the case. The problem is your activation was tied to your initial computer and certain HW upgrades makes Windows think you're using Windows on a new computer.

If you do find yourself with a non-genuine version of Windows after performing a hardware upgrade, replacing a failing component, or — in an extreme worst case scenario — upgrading a hardware driver or firmware that causes Windows to think you’re using a new component, you’ll need to activate Windows again with Microsoft.

To re-activate a Windows 7 PC, you’ll need to open the Windows Activation tool. To do so, click the Start button, type “Activate” into the Start menu, and click the Windows Activation shortcut. Select the “Show me other ways to activate” option and go through the wizard, selecting the “Use the automated phone system” option. You’ll then be given a toll-free number you can dial. If everything goes properly, you’ll be given a confirmation ID you can enter into the Windows Activation tool to make Windows genuine again. If the automated system fails, you’ll be put on the line with a Microsoft customer service representative. Explain your situation and they’ll hopefully allow you to re-active your installed copy of Windows, making it genuine again.

Taken from [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-your-windows-7-pc-genuine-again-after-a-hardware-upgrade/)